# Install deb package with all dependencies in same folder?

Tags: apt, dpkg, cache

I need to install multiple deb files of same software from apt cache in another ubuntu installation.

For example, I have all deb files of vlc in same folder(/var/cache/apt/archives). I need to install vlc with all dependencies satisfied. I cannot install it using `dpkg -i vlc*` because of dependencies.

Is there a solution to this. I have many software packgaes in my cache which I dont want to download again. Please help..

Answer (score 3):

Indeed you have many solutions:

- Copy all `.deb` files from `/var/cache/apt/archives` to the new  pc to  the directory `/var/cache/apt/archives`, or just copy the `.deb` of vlc dependencies only instead of copying all those debs. you can know the dependencies of vlc by command `apt-cache rdepends vlc`.
  Now once you have those debs in the `/var/cache/apt/archives` of the second system then you can run `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install vlc`.

***BUT*** this only works if the two systems have same  OS version and same package  version with same updates.<sub>[more info](https://askubuntu.com/a/630112/150504)</sub>

- Another solution which is **better** is to make your own repository so you can install any application you want without fearing of dependencies hell when offline installation. take a look: https://askubuntu.com/a/648969/150504

Answer (score 2):

**Answering your question:**

copy ALL of the debs from /var/cache/apt/archives to the new machine's /var/cache/apt/archives, then simply `sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get install vlc` as normal - it will pick up the .debs in the archive and install without downloading.

**Going a step further: install apt-cacher-ng instead**

On the first machine, do `sudo apt-get install apt-cacher-ng`.  Then do `sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf` and insert the string `Acquire::http::Proxy "http://127.0.0.1:3142/";` - this tells the machine to use the `apt-cacher-ng` instance on itself when it updates.  Now, import your existing cached debs - `sudo cp -a /var/cache/apt/archives/* /var/cache/apt-cacher-ng/_import/`, then open your browser to `http://localhost:3142/acng-report.html`, scroll down, and click `Start Import`.  Once that's done, do a quick `sudo apt-get update` - and, whew!  You've now got `apt-cacher-ng` running on your host machine, and every time your host machine downloads updates, it will cache them for both itself **and** any other machine on your network.

Finally, on your **second** machine, `sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf` and insert the string `Acquire::http::Proxy "http://first.machine.ip.address:3142/";` where *first.machine.ip.address* is the IP address of the machine you installed `apt-cacher-ng` on in the paragraph above - now, when you download updates on **either** machine, it will update the `apt-cacher-ng` on the first machine, and you won't have to download them again.  Very, very slick and easy once it's set up.