# How to create custom repository on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, repository

How to build custom repository server so that all client install packages from my machine.

what type of URL to add in `/etc/apt/sources.list` file on Client Machine. to fetch that particular package

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/529/how-to-set-up-an-apt-repository, https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/repository-howto/repository-howto#id3032359

Comment: How to create installation via LAn for Custom Packages

Answer (score 5):

**Installing  apache :**

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

**Creating needed directories**

Create a directory inside the webroot /var/www/

let's say name it repo.

```
sudo mkdir /var/www/repo
```

Now under repo you should create a directory for each architecture you want to use if you want more than one architecture.

For here i'll use amd64 for my 64bit systems. So, let's create this directory:

```
sudo mkdir /var/www/repo/amd64
```

**Creating Packages.gz file**

use the command `dpkg-scanpackages`

```
cd /var/www/repo/
sudo dpkg-scanpackages amd64 | gzip -9c > amd64/Packages.gz
```

**Add the new repo**

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/custom-repo.list
```

then add the line:

```
deb http://Your_Systme_IP/repo/ amd64/
```

Finally, update sources list:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now whenever you try to install any app, if you have its debs in your local repo then you install from it else then going to install from Internet.

Comment: What if my server is Fedora and my client uses Ubuntu Machine . will it work. Will be my client able to fetch the deb file

Comment: Ok !!! Thank you for your reply. will try and let you know

Comment: Hey   Not working

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://10.254.5.184/repo/amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

Comment: I have added ip address and fedora does not contain dpkg-scanpackages and I have added i deb file in amd64 folder

Comment: You use fedora as the repo server?!

Comment: YES I told you initially Server as Fedora 12 and client machine has Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: this will not work as it, I answered about concept not how to apply, you have to search for replacement of `dpkg-scanpackages` in fedora, but why to do that, just put this repo on some of clients with ubuntu! you need to install updates and dependencies periodically, how could you do that in fedora!! it's better to do it on some ubuntu client

Comment: Sorry repo server is CentOS and client machine is Ubuntu is it possible..?? to configure

Comment: You have to use `dpkg-scanpackages` with debian based OS only

Comment: Yes I understood but is it possible to host files for two different flavours i.e can I host CentOS repo server for Ubuntu Client .  IS it possible. I am not able to find solution on net

Comment: Yes you can but you should learn how to make offline repo in centOS

Comment: Hello I have created Ubuntu Machine and ran sudo dpkg-scanpackages amd64 | gzip -9c > amd64/Packages.gz command. What does this package do. What does this package contain and how to add my own deb file into these package

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://10.254.5.225/repo/amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

Comment: I already explain in the answer how to add your debs, just copy paste in the repo folder. to know about the package read its `man dpkg-scanpackages `